# Faster comparison for many DateTime's

Tags: c#, algorithm, datetime, big-o

I have been presented a task that I'm struggling with, in terms of efficiency.  I have a database that can have hundreds of thousands of transactions & people.  My goal is to find people who commonly have transactions near one another (Person X has had a transaction within 10 minutes of person Y, on 5 separate occasions).

I'm struggling to wrap my head around an efficient way to approach this.  The simplest approach is :

```
foreach(var doc in db.Transactions.OrderBy(d => d.TransactionID))
{
    foreach(var doc2 in db.Transactions.Where(d => d.TransactionID > doc.TransactionID))
    {
        if(doc2.DateCreated.IsBetween(doc.DateCreated,minutes))
        {
           // hit found  
        }
    }
}
```

(TransactionID is a bigint identity).  Once I have my list of `hits`, it would be easy to count occurrences.  But this is obviously pretty poor.  The run time is
[image]  which will be very slow at 1M+ transactions.  I've researched some algorithms, but I can't find any that apply to my situation.  Can anyone offer guidance on where to begin speeding this up?

Comment: Why order before filtering?

Comment: Hash all of the date times in epoch time then you can get a range

Comment: If performance is an issue you should consider dropping LINQ for this segment and make your very own query instead.

Comment: Good point, the result is the same without ordering

Comment: Use a custom SP for these kind of queries with large data.

Comment: If you order the transactions by datetime, then you can go sequentially through the list, comparing only those transactions that occur within the last 10 minutes. Although this is still *theoretically* O(n^2) (all transactions could be within a 10-minute period), in practice you'll only have to check each transaction against a few others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Few tips:

1. Do it on the database side (e.g. stored proc) - loading and processing 1M+ records will create overhead even if the algorithm is improved.
2. Separate all your data into buckets of size `10` minutes (assuming 10 minutes is your detection threshold). Then for each bucket you'd only need to check the adjacent ones, which should reduce the volume of comparison operations.
3. Make sure you operate on e.g. epoch time to avoid complex datetime operations.

Comment: thanks decPL, I'll definitely do it database side - the above example was mostly hammering out pseudocode.  Could you expand on `(2)` a bit? Are you saying order by the time created and then looping through each 10 minute segment?

Comment: I specifically didn't want to go into much details, because the actual implementation will differ greatly based on the way you'll be approaching this (if, for example, you'd follow Roy's approach (which by the way I'd strongly recommend you to do, provided you can factor in the operational costs) and, say, used OLAP cubes, then you'd have most of your work cut out for you). If pressed for a specific answer, I'd say - do that as follows: setup a temporary table holding a portion of your data (2 consecutive 'chunks' of size 10 minutes) - and only the relevant columns. [CONTINUED]

Comment: [CONT.] Operate on records in the first 'chunk' only, check if any data in your temp table matches your condition. Once you're done, discard the first 'chunk' and load up another one - repeat until finished.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to decPL's tips, you may want to set up a Data Warehouse with transaction data, that can then be analyzed, for instance, at night. This would mean you store data about your data in a separate database, and that database is then scanned for patterns using known algorithms. This is the way services such as Amazon come up with those "People who bought this, also bought..." suggestions.

The data in the warehouse can be optimized for fast processing, so it doesn't need to follow the same format as your actual ("source") database. The output of the analytical process (Reporting) can also be in a format that is easy to process afterward, possibly using LINQ like you do in your question.

For more info see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_warehouse and http://www.1keydata.com/datawarehousing/datawarehouse.html.